# How to get exception type without string name (ex.GetType().FullName) comparison in ASP.NET Page_Error handler?

Tags: .net, asp.net, exception, type-conversion, page-lifecycle

Is there a better way to do this than to check for Exception string?

I would rather have this catch-all error handled on the page, but for SOAP exceptions (web-service calls) I need to log the details of the actual exception that occured on the server, not the client.

The ".Detail.InnerText" property isn't in a generic exception, and can only be gotten after casting a generic exception to a SOAP exception.

```
    protected void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Context.Server.GetLastError();

        if (ex.GetType().FullName == "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException")
        {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException realException = (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException)ex;
            Response.Clear();

            Response.Output.Write(@"<div style='color:maroon; border:solid 1px maroon;'><pre>{0}</pre></div>", realException.Detail.InnerText);
            Response.Output.Write("<div style='color:maroon; border:solid 1px maroon;'><pre>{0}\n{1}</pre></div>", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);

            Context.ClearError();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

I would think there is a way to get at the underlying Exception's type without using string comparison...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try somethink like this:

```
var ex = Context.Server.GetLastError();

var soapEx = ex as SoapException;
if(soapEx != null)
{
    //Handle SoapException
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either use the `as` operator:

```
var ex = Context.Server.GetLastError();

var soapEx = ex as SoapException;
if(soapEx != null)
{
    //Handle SoapException
}
```

(See [Dima's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434030/how-to-get-exception-type-without-string-name-ex-gettype-fullname-comparison/4434091#4434091).)

Or compare type objects:

```
var ex = Context.Server.GetLastError();
if (ex.GetType() == typeof(SoapException) {
  ..
}
```

One assumes you will want to access some member of `SoapException`, the `as` approach avoids multiple type checks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ex is System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException)
{
    var soapEx = (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException)ex;
    // do your thing
}
```

Comment: Slightly better to use `as` operator so only one cast operator is needed as in @Dima's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434030/how-to-get-exception-type-without-string-name-ex-gettype-fullname-comparison/4434091#4434091).

Comment: Very true - that does indeed shave off one cast opcode, although the savings isn't as clear-cut.  IIRC, the instruction emitted for "as" casting is quite a bit more expensive than a C-style cast.  Maybe "is" does the same thing, though.  In any event, I tend to prefer my version for readability's sake.